# "Sticky" Analog Sticks – Solutions?

Tags: gaming

Sooner or later, every analog stick on every controller I've owned gets a little squidgy about returning to center. Fiddling with the deadzone, when available, can cover it fine at first when it's just a little wiggle, but I've walked off a cliff so many times because the stick just stays when I release it.

First, is there any sort of maintenance I can do to extend the life of a stick? I mostly use DualShock 2s because I like their feel, but I can't actually get inside the analog control box and, like, adjust springs or anything; I understand this to be the case with most gamepad analog sticks. Would lubrication help?

Second, when it comes to replacement — would Hall Effect analog sticks avoid this problem? Or is this something every stick can suffer from? Are there any easily-maintained modern gamepads out there?